# Force acrobat to render asymptote's figure with antialias

Tags: asymptote, linux, acrobat

**Does anybody know how to force Acrobat to display interactive 3D objects created by Asymptote with nice antialiasing?** (during PRC interaction).

In Acrobat Linux 9.4, I see this (note the pixelated result):

[image: noalias]

I tried all the setting in Acrobat's 3D settings with no luck, I also tried running `acroread` with a bunch of GL options.

`$ __GL_SYNC_TO_VBLANK=1 __GL_FSAA_MODE=9 __GL_LOG_MAX_ANISO=3 acroread figure.pdf`

I think I remember making it display antialiased 3D rendering in the past but I don't remember how.

[image]

Code:

`$ asy figure.asy -outformat pdf`

```
import unicode;
import palette;
import three;
currentprojection=orthographic(20,-40 , 70, center=true);
import graph3;
size(8cm, 0);
limits(O,X+Y+Z);
xaxis3(Label("$x$"), blue, arrow=Arrow3);
yaxis3(Label("$y$"), blue, arrow=Arrow3);
zaxis3(Label("$z$"), blue, arrow=Arrow3);
draw(scale3(0.1)*unitsphere);
```

This is the only documentation that I could find https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/using/displaying-3d-models-pdfs.html#3dpreferences

Note: it may be related to this issue with Mathematica for Linux, https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/198/antialiasing-in-3d

---

EDIT: Just tried Windows Acrobat 9.4.0 inside Linux Wine, and the 3D antialiasing works perfectly. (the preference in the 3D dialog is DirectX9, which is not available in the native Linux version.)

[image: acrowindows]

---

These are the libraries used by Acrobat Reader Linux, note that it uses `libGL.so`.

```
$ ldd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread 
    linux-gate.so.1 (0xf77a6000)
    libBIB.so => not found
    libBIBUtils.so => not found
    libACE.so => not found
    libAGM.so => not found
    libCoolType.so => not found
    libAXE8SharedExpat.so => not found
    libJP2K.so => not found
    libAdobeXMP.so => not found
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0xf7758000)
    libicuuc.so.36 => not found
    libssl.so.0.9.8 => not found
    libcrypto.so.0.9.8 => not found
    libxml2.so.2 => /lib/libxml2.so.2 (0xf75f3000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0xf75a5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0xf759f000)
    libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgdk_pixbuf_xlib-2.0.so.0 (0xf758d000)
    libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf70ca000)
    libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgdk-x11-2.0.so.0 (0xf7008000)
    libatk-1.0.so.0 => /lib/libatk-1.0.so.0 (0xf6fe4000)
    libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0 (0xf6fb9000)
    libpango-1.0.so.0 => /lib/libpango-1.0.so.0 (0xf6f6d000)
    libgobject-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgobject-2.0.so.0 (0xf6f19000)
    libglib-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libglib-2.0.so.0 (0xf6dd7000)
    libX11.so.6 => /lib/libX11.so.6 (0xf6c96000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0xf6ac8000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0xf694e000)
    libResAccess.so => not found
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0xf6930000)
    /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x56560000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/libz.so.1 (0xf6917000)
    liblzma.so.5 => /lib/liblzma.so.5 (0xf68ec000)
    libgmodule-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgmodule-2.0.so.0 (0xf68e6000)
    libgio-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgio-2.0.so.0 (0xf6751000)
    libpng16.so.16 => /lib/libpng16.so.16 (0xf671a000)
    libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 => /lib/libpangocairo-1.0.so.0 (0xf670d000)
    libXfixes.so.3 => /lib/libXfixes.so.3 (0xf6707000)
    libcairo.so.2 => /lib/libcairo.so.2 (0xf65c6000)
    libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 => /lib/libpangoft2-1.0.so.0 (0xf65b0000)
    libfontconfig.so.1 => /lib/libfontconfig.so.1 (0xf656d000)
    libXrender.so.1 => /lib/libXrender.so.1 (0xf6561000)
    libXinerama.so.1 => /lib/libXinerama.so.1 (0xf655d000)
    libXi.so.6 => /lib/libXi.so.6 (0xf654a000)
    libXrandr.so.2 => /lib/libXrandr.so.2 (0xf653e000)
    libXcursor.so.1 => /lib/libXcursor.so.1 (0xf6532000)
    libXcomposite.so.1 => /lib/libXcomposite.so.1 (0xf652e000)
    libXdamage.so.1 => /lib/libXdamage.so.1 (0xf652a000)
    libXext.so.6 => /lib/libXext.so.6 (0xf6516000)
    libgthread-2.0.so.0 => /lib/libgthread-2.0.so.0 (0xf6512000)
    libthai.so.0 => /lib/libthai.so.0 (0xf6508000)
    libffi.so.6 => /lib/libffi.so.6 (0xf6500000)
    libxcb.so.1 => /lib/libxcb.so.1 (0xf64da000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/libselinux.so.1 (0xf64b6000)
    libresolv.so.2 => /lib/libresolv.so.2 (0xf649a000)
    libharfbuzz.so.0 => /lib/libharfbuzz.so.0 (0xf6436000)
    libfreetype.so.6 => /lib/libfreetype.so.6 (0xf638e000)
    libpixman-1.so.0 => /lib/libpixman-1.so.0 (0xf62e1000)
    libEGL.so.1 => /lib/libEGL.so.1 (0xf62b2000)
    libxcb-shm.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-shm.so.0 (0xf62ad000)
    libxcb-render.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-render.so.0 (0xf62a2000)
    libGL.so.1 => /lib/libGL.so.1 (0xf61f0000)
    librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0xf61e7000)
    libexpat.so.1 => /lib/libexpat.so.1 (0xf61bf000)
    libdatrie.so.1 => /lib/libdatrie.so.1 (0xf61b5000)
    libXau.so.6 => /lib/libXau.so.6 (0xf61b1000)
    libpcre.so.1 => /lib/libpcre.so.1 (0xf613d000)
    libgraphite2.so.3 => /lib/libgraphite2.so.3 (0xf6111000)
    libbz2.so.1 => /lib/libbz2.so.1 (0xf60fe000)
    libX11-xcb.so.1 => /lib/libX11-xcb.so.1 (0xf60fa000)
    libxcb-dri2.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-dri2.so.0 (0xf60f4000)
    libxcb-dri3.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-dri3.so.0 (0xf60f0000)
    libxcb-present.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-present.so.0 (0xf60ec000)
    libxcb-randr.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-randr.so.0 (0xf60dc000)
    libxcb-xfixes.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-xfixes.so.0 (0xf60d2000)
    libxcb-shape.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-shape.so.0 (0xf60cd000)
    libxcb-sync.so.1 => /lib/libxcb-sync.so.1 (0xf60c5000)
    libxshmfence.so.1 => /lib/libxshmfence.so.1 (0xf60c2000)
    libgbm.so.1 => /lib/libgbm.so.1 (0xf60b4000)
    libwayland-client.so.0 => /lib/libwayland-client.so.0 (0xf60a7000)
    libwayland-server.so.0 => /lib/libwayland-server.so.0 (0xf6096000)
    libdrm.so.2 => /lib/libdrm.so.2 (0xf6085000)
    libglapi.so.0 => /lib/libglapi.so.0 (0xf603b000)
    libxcb-glx.so.0 => /lib/libxcb-glx.so.0 (0xf6020000)
    libXxf86vm.so.1 => /lib/libXxf86vm.so.1 (0xf6019000)
```

I uploaded the resulting PDF here: https://dropfile.to/G1yBf (it can only be opened with Acrobat)

Comment: Is the interactive functionality important to you? If not, you could add the `-noprc` flag to the `asy` compilation.

Comment: @CharlesStaats, yes, this happens after I click and rotate the figure interactively inside Acrobat. (The static image is decent and was rendered at the point of `asy` compilation.) I remember making this work in the past, but maybe at that time the graphics cards that I had was different (nVidia), now I have a cheap Intel video card.

Comment: Indeed, there is no antialiasing in the Linux version of AR. On the other hand, the newer versions X, XI on Windows nicely display the content with antaliasing.

Comment: @AlexG , Great, I won't loose any more time looking for a solution then. If you make it an answer, I'll accept it as authoritative. Did you figure out that yourself?

Comment: I just tried as you did. I am by no means an expert here. So I really don't know whether there might be or not some setting possible outside AR. Maybe the graphics card or OpenGL allow for configuring antialiasing?

Comment: @AlexG, I just tried Acrobat 9.4.0 for Windows running on Wine and the 3D antialiasing works perfectly. (see my edit).

Comment: Oh, you managed to install AcroRead in Wine!!! That's good news!

Comment: @AlexG, actually, Acrobat Reader 9 is the only I could install cleanly. Higher versions were problematic if not impossible. But who needs any other version of Acrobat Reader? :) 
  Downloaded from here ftp://ftp.adobe.com/pub/adobe/reader/win/9.x/ . At worst this shows that the video card is not the problem, but some bad default or limitation of `openGL/Mesa` in Linux (Fedora?). In fact I can't make it 3D-antialias `glxgears` at the moment.

Comment: @AlexG, I think I am close to a solution, in Mathematica the same problem occurs when the binary doesn't detect a certain version of `libGLU.so` in the path. By doing this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/101063/1963 I manage to make Mathematica do the antialiasing. I believe that if one can force `acroread` to use a newer version of `libGL???` one can get the same result. according to `ldd /opt/Adobe/Reader9/Reader/intellinux/bin/acroread` it uses `libGL.so.1 => /lib/libGL.so.1`.

Comment: By the way, I think this is similar to the problem of `acroread` by which it prints this message on start `(acroread:10492): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "murrine",`. It is solved by making a certain library available (in Fedora `gtk-murrine-engine.i686`, in Ubuntu `gtk2-engines-murrine:i386`).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about a feature of Adobe (Acrobat) Reader that is not supported on every platform or every version of the software.

Comment: Can you upload the rendered pdf to a file sharing site, for example dropbox?

Comment: @shrx,  https://dropfile.to/G1yBf (I removed the `-render 2` option from the `asy` command line so Acrobat opens the 3D picture directly. So it can be seen only in Acrobat.)